# How do I know whether my HTC One m8 has quick charge 2.0 capacity yet?

Tags: htc-one-m8

Although the HTC One m8 has a Qualcomm 801 processor, the Quick Charge 2.0 capacities has been disabled and the charger that the M8 comes with is a Quick Charge 1.0 one.

Apparently, some markets have had a firmware update that have enabled this feature.

I just got my phone so I was wondering, how do I know whether my m8 supports QC2.0?

I'm thinking about buying one but don't want to buy it if it is turns out my device isn't supported yet.